# Get the specific data from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner...

Say I Have a "Customers" workbook where sheet1 contains names of my customers. Say I also have an other "CustomerData" workbook where each sheet contains the data concerning each specific customer. I.e. sheet1 in "CustomerData" concerns customer1 from "Customers" workbook.

I would like to be able to klick on each customer in "Customers" workbook and get the specific data concerning that customer from the "CustomerData" workbook.

How could I accomplish such a thing?

Best Regards!

Comment: Refer this link   http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways that I know about getting data from another workbook.

- [ExecuteExcel4Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook)
- [ADODB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637376/query-my-excel-worksheet-with-vba/18640226#18640226)
- [Pulling Data from a closed workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet/17838174#17838174)
- Opening workbook to pull data from

```
Sub OpenWorkbookToPullData()

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\users\administrator\desktop\excelFile.xlsx"

    Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = openWs.Range("A1")

    openWb.Close (False)

End Sub
```