# Calculating mean/ standard deviation from data in a closed Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I know I can get a value from a closed workbook using
`ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\Location\Name\[excel1Test.xlsx]Sheet1'!R3C3")`
[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015693/getting-a-range-from-a-closed-workbook-into-an-array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015693/getting-a-range-from-a-closed-workbook-into-an-array)

and do standard deviation calculation on open work book by

```
Public Function MySdiv(Worksheet As String, lookRange As String) As Double
  Set myRange = Worksheets(Worksheet).Range(lookRange)
  answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(myRange)
  MySdiv = answer
End Function
```

I have a closed Excel, I know the name and the path and everything about this Excel and I want to perform a `.StDev` function on array `C1:C2000` for Sheet1 on `excel1Test.xlsx.`

The problem is getting the array of `C1:C2000`, and performing a `.StDev` on this array.

The `excel1Test.xlsx` has a lot of brothers, and they are all located in the same folder. They all look somewhat the same. In other words, they all have `C1:C2000` and `Sheet1`.

***I got it***

By using `ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)` and a `While` loop to find out the size of the array and a `For` loop to populate the array.

```
Function ArrayOut(strLocation As String, sheet As String, filename As String) As Double()

    Dim RowNum As Long, ref As String, arrWh() As Double, x As Integer, arg As String
    RowNum = 3
    ref = "C" & RowNum

    arg = " '" & strLocation & "[" & filename & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
            Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    x = 1
    Do While Not (ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg) = 0) ' while this cell doesn't equal to 0
        ReDim arrWh(0 To x - 1)
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
        ref = "C" & RowNum
        arg = " '" & strLocation & "[" & filename & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
            Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    
    RowNum = 3
    x = 1
    ref = "C" & RowNum
    arg = " '" & strLocation & "[" & filename & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
            Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
            
    For i = LBound(arrWh) To UBound(arrWh)
        arrWh(i) = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
        ref = "C" & RowNum
        arg = " '" & strLocation & "[" & filename & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
            Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    Next i

    RowNum = 3
    x = 1
    ArrayOut = arrWh
End Function
```

Then putting the result into this function:

```
Function AssiSTDVCal(Arr() As Double) As Double
    Dim Mean As Double, i As Long, x As Long, NewArr() As Double
    ReDim NewArr(UBound(Arr))
    
    Mean = MeanCal(Arr)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        NewArr(i) = (Arr(i) - Mean) * (Arr(i) - Mean)
    Next i
    
    For x = LBound(NewArr) To UBound(NewArr)
        Sum = Sum + NewArr(x)
    Next x
    AssiSTDVCal = Sqr(Sum / (x - 1))
    
End Function

Function AssistSTDVCal(MeanNum As Double, Arr() As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Long, NewArr(UBound(Arr)) As Double, Sum As Double
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        NewArr(i) = Abs(Arr(i) - MeanNum)
    Next i
    
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(NewArr) To UBound(NewArr)
        Sum = Sum + NewArr(x)
    Next x
    
    AssistSTDVCal = sqrt(Sum / (x - 1))
    
End Function

'Mean calculation
Function MeanCal(Arr() As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Long, Sum As Double, avg As Double
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Sum = Sum + Arr(i)
    Next i
    avg = Sum / i
    MeanCal = avg
End Function
```

This code is very VERY slow. I have 100+ Excel files, 6 sheets per file, anywhere from 5000+ to 100 rows per sheets...

I'm looking for help again to speed this code up.

Comment: Sorry, this might not be that helpful, but in order to pull alot of data from closed workbook, you will need ADO connection. See example here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267766/excel-vba-query-for-a-closed-workbook. I would suggest import the data from import data feature of Excel, and calculate stdev from there, the connection built by Excel will update upon refresh, so you don't have to worry about only taking a snapshot of the data.

Comment: thanks, this does sound like a good idea. and i will defenatelly give a look. however i don't think this will keep updating for all the closed excels in the folder.

Comment: Unfortunately not, you will probably need one linked table per sheet you are trying to pull data from, and the connection is only 1 way.