# instead of taking rowValue.Columns.Value2[1, 1] how can I compare header and take its value in excel adin?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, excel-addins

I have `excel ad-in project` and i'm `fetching values from excel` file like below by giving 
`index of sheet row`.

```
rowValue.Columns.Value2[1, 1];
rowValue.Columns.Value2[1, 2];
```

> Instead of giving sheet row numbers how can I get values based on Row Header Text?

[image]

Comment: maybe use [ADO and an SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637376/query-my-excel-worksheet-with-vba/18640226#18640226)

Comment: `rowValue.Columns.Value2[aCell.Row, aCell.Column];` Where `aCell` is the cell which contains the string that you want to search. Adapt [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) code for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually make my own VBA function called GetColumn.  It simply iterates through each column in row 1 until it reaches a cell with the text of rsHeading.  Just pass in the name of the heading you are looking for, and the function will return the column number of the heading.

```
Public Function GetColumn(ByRef rsHeading As String) As Long
    Dim lResult As Long, i As Long
    lResult = 0
    For i = 1 To 255
        If Me.Cells(1, i) = "" Then  'end of headings reached'
            lResult = i
        ElseIf InStr(Me.Cells(1, i), rsHeading) > 0 Then  'as long as the heading contains the text; it doesn't have to exactly equal that text'
            lResult = i
        End If
        If lResult <> 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    GetColumn = lResult
End Function
```

In your example, I would then call the function like so:

```
rowValue.Columns.Value2[1, GetColumn("Attribute")];
rowValue.Columns.Value2[1, GetColumn("IsMandatory")];
```

Comment: thanks but its  VBA function i'm working in excel adin project its c# code there muust be chnage in syntax but is there anything chnaged aprt from syntax like to take out excel header text value ?