# How to count matches in two columns and reset counter?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my data before:

```
A   Ron
A   Ron
B   Jeremy
C   Jeremy
C   Teddy
C   Teddy
C   Teddy
D   George
D   George
```

This is what I want to see after:

```
A   Ron 2
B   Jeremy  1
C   Jeremy  1
C   Teddy   3
D   George  2
```

Here is my non-working script:

```
Sub Macro()
i = 1
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If Range("A" & lngRow) = Range("A" & lngRow - 1) And _
    Range("B" & lngRow) = Range("B" & lngRow - 1) Then
        i = i + 1
        Range("C" & lngRow - 1).Value = i
    Rows(lngRow).Delete
End If
Next
i = 1
End Sub
```

Something is off with the counter, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: Would you be interested in non-VBA solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Your (second) `i = 1` is in the wrong place - you need to reset `i` every time there is a change in the "key":

```
Sub Macro()
    i = 1
    Dim lngRow As Long
    For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("A" & lngRow) = Range("A" & lngRow - 1) And _
           Range("B" & lngRow) = Range("B" & lngRow - 1) Then
            i = i + 1
            Range("C" & lngRow - 1).Value = i
            Rows(lngRow).Delete
        Else
            i = 1
            'Also need to set the previous "total" here, just in case
            'it is the only record for this "key"
            Range("C" & lngRow - 1).Value = i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about some SQL:

```
SELECT F1, F2, COUNT(*)
FROM [SheetName$]
GROUP BY F1, F2
```

Connect to the Excel worksheet using ADO, and paste the results into a new sheet using CopyFromRecordset.

A similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18472991/111794), and some references to ADO can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911760/111794).

Comment: That did it.  I knew it was something like that, but I got started down the wrong path, and couldn't recover all by myself.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Dictionary` object:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range, dataRng As Range

    Set dataRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In dataRng.Columns(1).Cells
            .Item(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(cell.Resize(, 2).Value)), "|")) = .Item(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(cell.Resize(, 2).Value)), "|")) + 1
        Next cell
        dataRng.ClearContents
        dataRng.Columns(1).Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        dataRng.Columns(1).Resize(.Count).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
        dataRng.Columns(3).Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!  Very cool!  I never knew you could do that with VBA!  Thanks for sharing!!!

Comment: Well, I think I'll run the one from YowE3K, just because I understand the logic better.  I really appreciate your effort though!!  It's definitely interesting to see how completely different methodologies can get the exact same results!!