# Merging and Adding Data in Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 sheets of data (from Dec 2014 to July 2015, separated month wise). Each sheet contains monthly data (e.g. Dec 2014 sheet contains data of dec 2014 in three columns namely AC #, Name, Amount).

Dec 2014 Contains Data as Mentioned Below:

```
A/C #     Name     Dec 2014
A12       ABC       100
A13       CBA       200
A14       BCA       300
```

Whereas January 2015 contains data as below

```
A/C #     Name     Dec 2014
A12       ABC       5
A13       CBA       300
*A15       IJK       900*
```

All sheets contains mostly same data but some additional data based on customers added in that month or amount. E.g. January 2015 may contain an additional client a/c #, name and amount of January 2015 as marked above.

I want a consolidated sheet of data where all data is arranged as below:

```
A/C #     Name     Dec 2014     Jan 2015     Feb 2015     Mar 2015     Apr 2015
A12       ABC       100          5
A13       CBA       200          300
A14       BCA       300          0
A15       IJK       0            900
```

Comment: Why does the January 2015 worksheet contain data from Dec 2014?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest connecting to the worksheets using ADODB. Then you can issue an SQL statement that will merge the records together.

This could be run from a VBScript, or from Excel.

For a similar strategy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911760/111794).